# How can i know that the AsyncTask that ran on the background is done ?

Tags: android

There is something that i don't understanding here ...

I define class

```
public class SendStringToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
{
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Now, i implimented the 'onPostExecute' method and i calling this background action from the main activity by using

```
 new SendStringToServer().execute("stringToSend");
```

Now, How can i know from the main activity that this action was done ? 
Hiw can i know from the main activity that this string was send already ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public Handler myHandler= new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void  handleMessage(Message msg){        

           if(msg.arg1 == 1){
                   //NOW in mainThread

           }
        }
    };

public class SendStringToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
{
     .
     .
     .
     onPostExecute(){
            ---------
        -----------------

       Message msg = myHandler.obtainMessage();
       msg.arg1 = 1;
       myHandler.sendMessage(msg);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You check the status of the AsyncTask using this method:

`asynctask.getStatus();` (More here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus%28%29)

Check also here for the possible results: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a global flag inside your activity

```
boolean sendComplete = false;
```

then in your onPostExecute after

```
new SendStringToServer().execute("stringToSend");
```

just add

```
sendComplete = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an event in you onpostexecute where the activity has a listener of.